# Set environment variables in `environment.yml`

Tags: environment-variables, anaconda, conda

Can I set environment variables in `environment.yml` files in [conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) environments?

Conda lets me [save environment variables in environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables) via the `env_vars.sh` script, but is there a way to automate the process of creating `env_vars.sh` files in the `activate.d`, `deactivate.d` directories according to some specification of environment variables within `environment.yml`, for a reproducible environment with, say, `MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU`?

Comment: From your link: *When you run* `source activate analytics`, *the environment variables* `MY_KEY` *and* `MY_FILE` *are set to the values you wrote into the file. When you run* `source deactivate`, *those variables are erased.* Can you clarify what you want to do that's additional to this?

Comment: @nekomatic I've edited the question.

Comment: Struggling with this as well.  I found [anaconda-project](http://anaconda-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/work-with-variables.html), which handles this, but seems a bit overkill.  It seems like it's an [open issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6649) for conda.  Did you find an answer?

Comment: Not really, no. I never managed to fully automate this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like this was added in Conda **v4.9**!

There is documentation at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables

> Environment variables set using `conda env config vars` will be retained in the output of `conda env export`. Further, you can declare environment variables in the `environment.yml` file as shown here:
>
> ```yaml
> name: env-name
> channels:
>   - conda-forge
>   - defaults
> dependencies:
>   - python=3.7
>   - codecov
> variables:
>   VAR1: valueA
>   VAR2: valueB
> ```

Older versions of conda will complain;

```
EnvironmentSectionNotValid: The following section on 'environment.yml' is invalid and will be ignored:
 - variables
```

Comment: thanks for the hint that it's only available since v4.9! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to use other (predefined) environment variables in the values, e.g. `$HOME`