# Saving environment variables in Conda environment.yaml files

Tags: conda

I've figured out how set environment variables when activating my conda environment via scripts at

```
$CONDA_PREFIX\etc\conda\activate.d\env_vars.ps1
```

But, if I run `conda env export > environment.yaml`, it doesn't capture this environment variable shenanigans. Which seems like it would be awkward to create a clean environment.yaml file to share or to reuse. Every time I delete/recreate an environment, I need to manually set up the directories/files to set the environment variables.

Is there a way to capture custom environment variables in the environment.yaml file? I'm picturing being able to create an environment from a yaml file and get the environment variables as well but it doesn't look possible from what I can tell.

I don't immediately see in the docs a reference to scripting or pluggability for the environment.yaml format, but it seems like if that were possible maybe those files could be created from a script embedded in or referenced from environment.yaml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set environment variables in \`environment.yml\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710371/set-environment-variables-in-environment-yml)

Comment: cool, thanks. yeah, duplicate with good answer.